# CSS/SASS Select elements based on class, but exclude certain elements with same class

Tags: html, css, sass

I am going to slap myself once an answer comes in... so what I am trying to do is add a border to all elements with `<anyElement class="required active">`, but not to `<select class="required active">`. Difference being the `<select>` element.

Example tried lol:

```
.required.active, :not(select.required.active) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Using CSS3 and/or SASS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for.

As i've understood on your post, you only need to exclude **< select >** tags with "required" and "active" classes.

```css
:not(select).required.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="required active">
  qwe
</div>
<p class="required active">
  qwe
</p>
<input type="text" class="required active" value="qwe">
<select class="required active">
  <option value="1">qwe</option>
</select>
```

In this snippet, we used the :not() selector of CSS3 to eliminate the `<select>` tag with "required" and "active" classes.

For further explanation about the :not() CSS Selector, please refer to these links:

[Dev. Mozilla Org: (CSS :not() Selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

[W3Schools.COM: (CSS :not() Selector)](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

Comment: Perfect - avoids the select tags, but borders all others with the classes.  All done in the least amount of code!

Comment: Happy coding @RooksStrife! :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking can be achieved through this:
CSS:

```css
.required.active:not(select).required.active{
border: 1px solid red;
color:blue
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
  <p class="required active">Hello</p>
  <p class="required active">Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <select class="required active">
    <option>Hello<option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

let me know if you need any other help.